# Reading data from file and creating a file and writing data is the file is not found

Tags: perl, file

I have come into a situation where I need to read 2 lines data (username and password) from a file called login.txt(in current dir). After reading the username (1st line) has to be stored in $user and the second line (password) has to be stored in $pass.

In case if this file is not found, I have to prompt the user to enter the username and password and store it in $user and $pass and create the file login.txt(in currect dir) and write these two lines into the file.

```
my $user;
my $pass;

my $login = "login.txt";


unless (-e $login) {
print "Entering first time execution mode....!\n";
sleep(2);

print "Enter username:\n";
$user = <STDIN>;
chomp($user);
print "Enter password:\n";
$pass = <STDIN>;
chomp($pass);
unless(open LINFO, '>'.$login) {
# Die with error message 
# if we can't open it.
die "\nUnable to create $login\n";
}

print LINFO "$user\n";
print LINFO "$pass\n";

close LINFO;
} 


if (-e $login) {

open (LINFO, '$login') or die "Cant open\n";

while( my $line = <LINFO>)  {   
print $line; 
chomp($line); 

if    ($. == 1) { $user = $line; }

elsif ($. == 2) { $pass = $line; }

last if $. == 2;

}

close LINFO;

}

print $pass;
print $user;
```

When the file is doesn't exists everything works fine (even $user and $pass gets printed), but will get a error message as below :-

```
readline() on closed filehandle LINFO at loginfile.pl line 43.
```

If the file already exists then I get following error

```
readline() on closed filehandle LINFO at loginfile.pl line 43.
Use of uninitialized value $pass in print at loginfile.pl line 59.
Use of uninitialized value $user in print at loginfile.pl line 60.
```

Not sure whats the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it exiting if it doesn't find the login.txt file? Because of the `die` statement? Here's [`perldoc -f die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html):

> die LIST
>
> die raises an exception. Inside an eval the error message is stuffed
>   into $@ and the eval is terminated with the undefined value. If the
>   exception is outside of all enclosing evals, then the uncaught
>   exception prints LIST to STDERR and exits with a non-zero value. If
>   you need to exit the process with a specific exit code, see exit.

While this is not terribly clear (to be precise, its horribly unclear for a newbie), you should probably know that `die` means that the program exits, execution stops there.

When using `open`, this is the recommended practice, since often any error in open calls should be considered fatal. You however ignore this `open` call and use another `open` on the same file handle later on in that block. The only reason I can see for

```
unless(open LINFO, $login) {
```

Would then be that you are trying to determine if the file exists, and you can read it. For this purpose, you can use [the `-X` commands](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), e.g.

```
if (-e $login)     # if file exists
if (-r $login)     # effective uid/gid can read file
...
```

Comment: I worked on your answers, I'm facing a little bug although the script works. Please check the edited question

Comment: @mac The only fatal error is that you use single quotes around the file name when you open the file, `open LINFO, '$login'`. This statement should cause the script to die, because the single quotes prevents variable interpolation and the script tries to open a file named `$login` (which should not exist). Since it does not die, it is not consistent with the errors you report. Your errors are suggest that the open failed, but the script did not die. So, my guess is that you did something different than you say you did.

Comment: To solve the interpolation, remove the quotes. You never need to quote a variable, only strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the conditions for `if` and `elsif` in parentheses. Also be careful where to use `=` and `==`. This should work for you:

```
if    ($. == 1) { $user = $line;  }
elsif ($. == 2) { $pass = $line;  }
```